# Expected number of games for three-player gambler's ruin

Tags: pr.probability, martingales

Three gamblers each start with $a$, $b$ and $c$ chips, respectively.
In each round of the game, a gambler is selected uniformly at random
to give up one chip, and one of the remaining two gamblers is selected
uniformly at random to receive that chip. The game ends when there are
only two players remaining with chips, that is, one player goes
bankrupt. Let $X_n$, $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ be the respective number of chips
the three players have after round $n$, so $(X_0, Y_0, Z_0) = (a, b,  c)$.

Here, we have $M_n = X_nY_nZ_n + \frac{1}{3}n(a + b + c)$ being a martingale, and we can define $N := \inf\{n : X_nY_nZ_n = 0\}$ to be a stopping time of $M_n$. I want to show that the game terminates almost surely, i.e. $\mathrm{E}[N] < \infty$. I'm not sure how I can go about doing that.

In my attempt, I observe that I can (somewhat) extend this to a two-player gambler's ruin by "lengthening" the game to where the game ends when one gambler gets all the chips, and the game will still terminate almost surely. However, it's not exactly the same as two-player, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that in general, "the game terminates almost surely" and "$E[N] < \infty$" are not equivalent.  In this case, though, you have a finite Markov chain with one absorbing state (bankruptcy) which is accessible from every other state.  Then the hitting time of that state must have finite expected value.  One way to see it is to change the game so that when one player goes bankrupt, the game starts over; then you have an irreducible finite-state Markov chain, which must be positive recurrent.

Comment: Alternatively, note that $M_{n \wedge N}$ is a martingale, and that $M_{n \wedge N} \ge \frac{1}{3}(n \wedge N) (a+b+c)$.  Hence $\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c) E[n \wedge N] \le E[M_{n \wedge N}] = E[M_0] = abc$.  By monotone convergence $E[n \wedge N] \to E[N]$, so we conclude $\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c) E[N] \le abc$ and in particular $E[N] < \infty$.

Comment: I'm sure you saw that already, but in fact once you know that $N<\infty$ a.s. by either method, the same martingale argument gives you $abc=\frac{a+b+c}3E[n\wedge N]+E[P_{n\wedge N}]$, where $P_k$ is the product $X_kY_kZ_k$. So the expectation of $N$ is actually precisely $3abc/(a+b+c)$.